# error while importing webdriver from selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The first thing I wanted to do is, installing Selenium in Windows and import webdriver from selenium.

So, I installed Selenium with *pip install selenium* and tried to import webdriver  with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

But I got the error:

*File "C:\Users\VIJAY\Desktop\selenium.py", line 2, in 
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'*

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Rename your file from selenium.py to something else. Also, make sure there is nothing named selenium in your desktop folder. You are probably not importing the library, but rather a python file.

Answer (score -1):

Change your program name to something else like scraping if you are practicing it.
Or else try installing it from the python console.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
```